# Add a shadow below the color in status bar

Tags: android, android-toolbar, android-styles, android-statusbar

Hello i am having troubles adding both a color and a shadow to the status bar so it looks a bit darkened.

What i have right now is:

[image]

and what i want to do is:

[image]

My styles.xml is:

```
<resources>
    <!-- Base application theme. -->
    <style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">
        <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
        <item name="colorPrimary">@color/colorPrimary</item>
        <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>
        <item name="colorAccent">@color/colorAccent</item>
        <item name="android:windowActionBarOverlay">true</item>
        <item name="android:windowContentOverlay">@null</item>
        <item name="android:actionBarStyle">@style/FullscreenActionBarStyle</item>
    </style>

    <style name="FullscreenActionBarStyle" parent="Widget.AppCompat.ActionBar">
        <item name="android:background">@color/colorPrimaryDarkShadow</item>
    </style>
</resources>
```

and my colors.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
    <color name="colorPrimary">#607d8b</color>
    <color name="colorPrimaryDark">#607d8b</color>
<resources>
```

but for some reason i endup with Toolbar and status bar to have exactly the same color. I tried adding `android:elevation="8dp"` as suggested in another post but still the same result. Can anyone guide me through it?

Comment: mabye you can change the colours to make the app colour darker? i dont do xml and android programming so i dont know.. i would just try using a darker color? or does the status bar change based on the app colour?

Comment: yes that would be a solution but in google material design guidelines it suggests that we should add a shadow to the status bar and use the same color as toolbar

Comment: change colorPrimaryDark= #435761

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have two options:

1. Change `colorPrimaryDark` to the color you would like to use under
   the status bar. The AppCompat themes automatically set the status bar 
   color to `colorPrimaryDark`.

   Since you are using [Material Blue Grey 500](https://material.google.com/style/color.html#color-color-palette) [`#607D8B`] as your
   `colorPrimary`, Google recommends using the 700 version for
   `colorPrimaryDark`; which is `#455A64`.
2. Set the status bar to translucent in your theme using
   [`windowTranslucentStatus`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/R.attr.html#windowTranslucentStatus). This will add a semi-transparent black
   background to the status bar.

   ```
   <item name="android:windowTranslucentStatus">true</item>
   ```

   You will also have to add [`android:fitsSystemWindows`](https://medium.com/google-developers/why-would-i-want-to-fitssystemwindows-4e26d9ce1eec#.8s03bh6tc) to your layout in
   order to make use of this.

Answer (score 0):

change your theme `parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar"` to `parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light"`

```
<style name="AppTheme.Me" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light">
    <item name="colorPrimary">@color/colorPrimary</item>
    <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>
    <item name="colorAccent">@color/colorAccent</item>
</style>
```

Comment: you say change this to this and both are the same?

Comment: change to Theme.AppCompat.Light

Comment: still the same problem....does not change to darker color....i forgot to mention that both colorPrimary and colorPrimaryDark have the same color